# httpd virtual host issue with facebook fetch

Tags: facebook, apache, virtualhost

i have some issues with httpd virtual host, i need some helps.

I have a CentOS 6.5 VPS, httpd installed. I have 2 domain www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com

In httpd.conf, i put these code to activate virtual host

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1
        ServerName www.domain1.com
        ServerAlias domain1.com *.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com
        ServerName www.domain2.com
        ServerAlias domain2.com *.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

When i visit domain1.com and domain2.com, it's working correct.

But, when i share with facebook, it's not correct. When i share domain1.com, it's show the domain1.com description & thumbnails (good). When i share domain2.com, it does not show the domain2 info, it shows domain1.com description. However, it shows domain2.com info when i share the link xxx.domain2.com (xxx = any word).

I'm using cloudFlare and i tried to purge cache or change www to CNAME, but nothing happened.

Anyone knows these issue? Please help :)

Thank you!!!

**Solved:**

Add meta prop to header of index file in domain2

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain2.com" />
```

Comment: Send the URLs through Facebook’s [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) first to check whether your OG meta data is alright.

Comment: Problems solved! Thank you!!!